# How to change orientation mode only when some fragments are visible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I'm building an app with an `Activity` with can load different `Fragments`. I want it to remain in portrait mode and allow landscape only when some specific `Fragments` are visible.

If I set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for my `Activity` it's locked to this mode and I can't find any way to detect orientation changes.

If I don't set it an detect orientation change using

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in the `androidManifest` and

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 
}
```

in my `Activity` to detect the changes, the `Activity` is recreated every time the orientation is changes.

How can I keep my `Activity` in portrait mode (without redrawing it on orientation changes) and only redraw it when a given `Fragment` is visible?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, donot use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the base Activity.

Override `setUserVisibleHint()` in each fragment.

In the portrait only fragments use :

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity a = getActivity();
        if(a != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

In the landscape only fragments use :

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            Activity a = getActivity();
            if (a != null)
                a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's never called (using API 19)!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found is to add

```
@Override
public void onResume (){
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}

@Override
public void onPause (){
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

in the `Fragments` which should change layouts according to the orientation.